# How to access $ionicModal object elements by id in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have posted the same question in different way here [SiganaturePad](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/signature-pad-in-ionic-using-modal/10422).Now I dont have idea to handle this case.
I am using $ionicModal to populate the SignaturePad with canvas as below.

```
  /*SignaturePad*/
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/signature.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    alert('sign 1');

    var canvas=angular.element("#signature-pad");
    siganturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
    alert('sign');
    signaturePad.minWidth = 5;
    signaturePad.maxWidth = 10;
    signaturePad.penColor = "rgb(66, 133, 244)";    
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();    
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  $timeout($scope.openModal, 200);
```

But am getting error like "**Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element"**

I can predict the issue.that I am accessing elements via id in wrong way.So could you Please suggest How to Access the SiganaturePad to Initialize and access its subElements (clear and Save button) in $ionicModal.

Comment: If you include jquery before angular it will use it instead of it's built-in jqlite implementation.

Comment: yea ,I have tried that,But if i use jquery before the angular js.the Angular js functions is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the built-in jQuery lite is very limiting. Luckily, looking up an element by ID is pretty easy:

So instead of:

```
 var canvas=angular.element("#signature-pad");
```

just do:

```
 var canvas=angular.element(document.getElementById("signature-pad"));
```

Comment: .Thanks I have tried your solution its working,I have checked the canvas object is defined by angular.isUndefined(canvas).its return false.

Comment: my other query is ,How can i access my other elements var canvas= angular.element(document.getElementById("signature-pad")),
    clearButton = angular.element(canvas.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"));

Comment: That should be working, what is happening in that case?